# Typing Redux Store with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Here are the action creators types:

```
    export type Calculation = {
      type: string;
    };
    
    export type AddAndSubtract = {
      type: string;
      value: number;
    };
    
    export type GetUserInput = {
      type: string;
      value: HTMLTextAreaElement;
    };

export type DispatchActions = Calculation | GetUserInput | AddAndSubtract;
```

And this is the store:

```
export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action: DispatchActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case "DECREMENT":
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
    case "ADD_5":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + action.value };
    case "SUBTRACT_5":
      return { ...state, count: state.count - action.value };
    case "RESET":
      return { ...state, count: action.value };
    case "GET_USER_INPUT":
      return { ...state, userInput: action.value };
    case "MULTIPLY":
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count * state.userInput,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

However typescript show error: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'DispatchActions'. Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Calculation'. How may I solve this ?

Comment: The reason is export type Calculation = {
      type: string;
    };
  where value key does not present and on other's value exist's. In order to fix it add value key in it. Error will go away!

Comment: but then typescript is only reading the first type in `DispatchActions` right ?, will it be able to know which type is being used ?

Comment: Not exactly, you are using union operator, Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html you will understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Addition of above comment. This will also work!

Add value key in Calculation, you are using union type's.

```
export type Calculation = {
      type: string;
      value: number
    };
```

Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html for more help and reason of error!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use union type here. You just need to create the single type DispatchAction:

```
export type DispatchAction = {
      type: string;
      value: number | HTMLTextAreaElement;
}

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action: Partial<DispatchAction>) =>
```

OR

```
export type DispatchAction = {
      type: string;
      value?: number | HTMLTextAreaElement;
}

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action: DispatchAction) => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As others are indicating, the problem is coming from how you are using the union.  As you’ve written it, Typescript doesn’t have any way of knowing *which* of the possible types in the union you are passing and so it has to assume it could be any of them.  For example, it would be perfectly valid with your typing to pass an action like this:

```
const badAction:Calculation = {
  type: “SUBTRACT_5”
}
```

Which wouldn’t work with your code at runtime—and that’s exactly what TS is telling you.  You could handle by having a weak type like the answers above are suggesting.  Or you could use string literals to provide stronger typing with unions as explained [in the Redux docs.](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-actions--action-creators)